# Who are these Lego superheroes?

Tags: marvel, dc, character-identification, lego

Recently my wife bought me this amazing gift: it's a frame with a set of Lego superheroes/villains from the Marvel and DC universes. Image below.

[image: Lego Superheroes and Villains]

Now, I know *most* of them, but I'm not able to place a few, here's how they sit (the ones  with <sup>*</sup> next to them are the unknowns):

<sup>[Left to right]</sup>

**Top Row**

- Captain America
- Spiderman
- Wolverine
- The Hulk
- **Unknown 1<sup>*</sup>** - Falcon?
- **Unknown 2<sup>*</sup>**

**Second Row from Top**

- The Flash
- The Joker
- Batman
- *[Me](//scifi.stackexchange.com/users/21267/mooz)* (IT Nerd Guy)
- Superman
- Iron Man

**Second Row from Bottom**

- Nick Fury
- HawkEye<sup>*</sup>
- Deadpool<sup>*</sup>
- Loki
- **Unknown 3<sup>*</sup>** - Antman?
- **Unknown 4<sup>*</sup>**

**Bottom Row**

- Wonder Woman
- Batman<sup>*</sup>
- Aqua Man
- **Unknown 5<sup>*</sup>**
- Catwoman
- Thor

## Who are these Lego Superheroes and Villains?

Comment: Can i just say, that's an awesome way to display some heroes.

Comment: @RogueJedi No, as far as I can tell they're all real Lego; there's a pretty extensive set of Marvel and DC Lego sets, and they've released some exclusives based on their video games

Comment: @JasonBaker It might just be the photo, but something looks a little strange about them.

Comment: @RogueJedi Probably the photo. I will get a better one at some point :)

Comment: @RogueJedi I sort of lied; the Hawkeye appears to be a custom job; I found [an Etsy store](https://www.etsy.com/listing/239143424/hawkeye-purple-suit-variant-custom) selling them, but I'm not sure if it's 3d-printed, or a modified minifigure, or what

Comment: Google reverse image search?

Comment: Clearly off topic, but you have a neat wife

Comment: You can find them all here: http://www.firestartoys.com/Shop/LEGO-Minifigures/Super-Heroes-LEGO-Minifigures.html

Comment: How is there no documentation with this?!

Comment: why is Flash holding red sticks? Is he being mistaken / substituted for Daredevil?

Comment: Awesome gift...your wife's definitely a keeper.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

### First Row

- [Captain America](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America)

  [image]

  I'm pretty sure this is *The Avengers* version of the Cap minifig, although it's hard to tell. I'm basing this judgment off his belt, mainly, which in the question image appears to be very thick red; *Avengers* cap is the only one who has thick red bands on his belt in those locations.

  This variant is only available with the [Captain America's Avenging Cycle](https://shop.lego.com/en-CA/Captain-America-s-Avenging-Cycle-6865?p=6865) set, released as a tie-in for the 2012 *Avengers* movie.
- [Spider-man](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Spider-Man)

  [image: Lego Spidey]

  Based on the defined musculature on his chest, this is the "Ultimate Spider-man" variant of the Spidey minifig. Ultimate Spidey is available in almost every Spidey set released between 2012 and 2016

  The rope in his hands is, maybe obviously, meant to represent one of Spidey's web-ropes
- [Wolverine](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Wolverine)

  [image: Wolverine]

  This is the "Astonishing Wolverine" variant (you can tell because of the blue vertical stripes on either side of his chest. This is a rare variant (although Wolvie is a pretty rare minifig to begin with), and is only available in the [Wolverine's Chopper Showdown](https://www.amazon.ca/LEGO-Heroes-Wolverines-Chopper-Showdown/dp/B007GE5X7S) set
- [Hulk](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Hulk)

  [image]

  This is notably the Hulk minifigure, which was given away as a promotional item with LEGO Store purchases in May 2012. The Hulks that you can get in the regular sets are more...hulking.
- [Falcon](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Falcon)

  [image]

  Based on the guns, I think this one might be an off-brand, not the official Lego figure. I obviously can't be certain, but the picture I've included above is of an off-brand, and it's the only one I could find of Falcon carrying those guns.

  In any case, classic Falcon is only available in the [Hulk Lab Smash](https://www.amazon.ca/LEGO-Superheroes-Hulk-Lab-Smash/dp/B00IANU50O) set (which also doesn't have guns for Falcon)
- [Cyborg](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Cyborg)

  [image]

  Cyborg is a newcomer; his minifig was only released in September of 2015. You can get him as a Dimensions Set, or from the [Darkseid Invasion](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/76028_Darkseid_Invasion) set, which is also the only place you can get Hawkman

### Second Row

- [The Flash](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Flash)

  [image]

  This is the "New 52" Flash variant, available in [Batman: The Riddler Chase](https://shop.lego.com/en-AU/Batman-The-Riddler-Chase-76012) and [Gorilla Grodd Goes Bananas](https://shop.lego.com/en-CA/Gorilla-Grodd-goes-Bananas-76026). The rods he's holding are presumably meant to represent the Speed Force, and are available in [lots of sets](https://brickset.com/parts/4124108/light-sword-blade) (the part started out as a lightsaber blade); as far as I know, they're not actually distributed with Flash.
- [Joker](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Joker)

  [image]

  Based on the green checkered waistcoat, this is the 2012 version of the Joker minifig. He's available in a few of the non-movie tie-in Batman sets
- [Batman](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman)

  [image]

  This is actually a special Batman figure; you can only get the black costume with wings from the [Arkham Asylum Breakout](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/10937_Batman:_Arkham_Asylum_Breakout) set
- [Computer Programmer (not, strictly speaking, a superhero)](http://www.lego.com/en-us/minifigures/characters/computer-programmer-0c248844ec9d4245a5c17479a208e45b)

  [image]

  This happy fellow isn't in any sets; you can only get him by buying a Series 7 minifigure bag
- [Superman](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman)

  [image]

  This is the comic variant Superman minifig. He debuted as a Comic-Con exclusive in 2011, but has since appeared in a few sets, such as [Darkseid Invasion](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/76028_Darkseid_Invasion) and [Brainiac Attack](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/76040_Brainiac_Attack)
- [Iron Man Mk. 6](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Iron_Man)

  [image]

  You can tell it's the Mark 6 because of the triangular Arc Reactor light on his chest. The Mk. 6 is only available in two sets: [Loki's Cosmic Cube Escape](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/6867_Loki%27s_Cosmic_Cube_Escape) and [Iron Man vs. Fighting Drone](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/30167_Iron_Man_vs._Fighting_Drone)

### Third Row

- [Nick Fury](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Nick_Fury)

  [image]

  This is the "Ultimate Spider-man" Nick Fury minifigure; he's only available in the [Spider-Man: Spider-Cycle Chase](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/Spider-Man-Spider-Cycle-Chase-76004) set.
- [Hawkeye](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Hawkeye)

  [image]

  Unlike the rest, this one doesn't appear to be an official Lego minifigure; the official one has red accents, not purple. This purple variant seems to be a custom job, from [this Etsy store](https://www.etsy.com/listing/239143424/hawkeye-purple-suit-variant-custom)
- [Carnage](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Carnage)

  [image]

  So far, Carnage has only appeared in a single set: [Carnage's SHIELD Sky Attack](https://shop.lego.com/en-CA/Carnage-s-SHIELD-Sky-Attack-76036)
- [Loki](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Loki)

  [image]

  It looks like you have the Avengers variant of Loki, which appears in a few of the tie-in sets for the 2012 *Avengers* film (such as [Loki's Cosmic Cube Escape](https://shop.lego.com/en-CA/Loki-s-Cosmic-Cube-Escape-6867?p=6867)); however, the standard Loki minifigure comes with a bright green cape, while the one you have appears to be wearing a black cape (although that may just be a trick of the light; it's hard to tell).

  Also note that Loki's Scepter comes [in](https://brickset.com/parts/4610762/shaft-%C3%B83-2-w-cored-%C3%B83-2-hole) two [pieces](https://brickset.com/parts/4646866/mini-sai-w-%C3%B83-2) (one of which was later re-used in Ninjago); in most official images these two pieces are together, but in yours he's holding one piece in each hand.
- [Ant-Man](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Ant-Man)

  [image]

  This seems to be another custom job, available from [this Etsy store](https://www.etsy.com/sg-en/listing/231644596/custom-ant-man-minifigure-lego-size); the design is based on the classic Ant-Man look, while official products tend to follow the design from the films.
- [Brainiac](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Brainiac)

  [image]

  Brainiac is only available in the [Brainiac Attack](https://shop.lego.com/en-CA/Brainiac-Attack-76040) set.

### Fourth Row

- [Wonder Woman](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman)

  [image]

  This is the comics variant of Diana, available in [Superman vs. Power Armour Lex](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/Superman-vs-Power-Armor-Lex-6862) and a Dimensions set. She also apparently appears in an exclusive [*The Lego Movie* tie-in set](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/The_LEGO_Movie_Exclusive_Set) distributed to members of the press.
- [Bizarro-Batman](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Bizarro_Batman)

  [image]

  By most accounts, Batzarro is a very rare minifigure; as near as I can tell, the only way to get him is with the home video release of the [*Justice League vs. Bizarro League*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OQRUB70) Lego movie. I wouldn't be entirely surprised if this one was off-brand.
- [Aquaman](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Aquaman)

  [image]

  This is the comics Aquaman, rather than the guyliner-tastic *Justice League* variant, available in a few Aquaman sets release pre-2017
- [Hawkman](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Hawkman)

  [image]

  As I mentioned above, Hawkman is only available in the [Darkseid Invasion](https://shop.lego.com/en-DE/Darkseid-Invasion-76028) set. Note that the set comes with two different sets of wings: one extended (for flying) and one folded up (for going through narrow doorways). Whoever put together your product put both sets on him, hence why he looks like he has butterfly wings
- [Catwoman](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Catwoman)

  [image]

  Catwoman is a bit unusual because no two sets seem to have quite the same version of her minifig; I'm pretty sure, however, that you have the variant appearing in [Catwoman Catcyle Chase](https://shop.lego.com/en-CA/Catwoman-Catcycle-City-Chase-6858) (which also contains a diamond and that brown whip)
- [Thor](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Thor)

  [image]

  That looks like the Avengers version of the Thor minifig, which appears in a few of the sets that tie into the 2012 *Avengers* film (such as [Hulk's Helicarrier Breakout](https://shop.lego.com/en-CA/Hulk-s-Helicarrier-Breakout-6868?p=6868))

Comment: Programmers are heroes too <3

Comment: The Computer Programmer is often used as a stand-in for Clark Kent.

Comment: @CreationEdge Makes sense; still, if this was a gift for Mooz it stands to reason that it's meant to represent him

Comment: Wait, you mean to tell me @Mooz is Superman?!

Comment: Why does ant man have spiders?

Comment: @CreationEdge I'd never say that. I'm just saying I've never seen them in the same room

Comment: I'm nodding. Nod, nod. Looks right to me.

Comment: Oh thank goodness! I was like "Oh, it's Deadpool? It...really looks like Carnage tho."

Comment: I think the Falcon figure is official; the [Lego Wikia page](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Falcon) confirms he has translucent wings, and the body design looks right. Don't know where the guns came from, though...

Comment: @TomPotts You might be right; but with the quality of the off-brands (I found a *bunch* of them, not to mention the custom ones being sold on Etsy), it really is hard to tell

Comment: http://brickset.com/sets/76018-1/Avengers-Hulk-Lab-Smash Parts listing for set with Falcon, official color is Translucent Red for wings. Also, the paint job matches. The Falcon only appears in that set, and it's the proper cartoon version. Those guns, however, are most likely custom.

Comment: Logged in just to say excellent job not only naming the heroes but tracking down their sources, specifying how rare the characters are, and even finding the the custom Etsy stores some of them were bought from. Likewise, congrats to @Mooz for having an awesome wife willing to track down all of those characters just to get him this truly one of a kind gift.

Comment: `Based on the guns and the slight translucency of the wings, I think this one might be an off-brand, not the official Lego figure. I'm not positive, though.`  The official Lego Falcon *does* have translucent wings.  However, I still believe this is an off-brand because of the guns.  For @Mooz, you can always tell if a minifig is official by looking under the feet.  `©LEGO` will be imprinted on the underside of the toes.

Comment: @Broklynite me too.. also, I want one.

Comment: Tempted to downvote because you say computer programmers aren't super heroes. I am as super as super heroes get! But, I'll upvote anyway for the awesome answer.

Comment: @istrasci Thinking you're probably right; the off-brand is the only one I've seen with the guns. Not that it *really* matters

Comment: Oh I thought purple Batman would be Batgirl (http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20111027011739/batman/images/0/01/Yvonne-Craig-Batgirl-image-2-475x600.jpg) but I guess not.

Comment: @Catija I think those are octopuses.

Comment: Why does Falcon have an evil face?

Answer (score 18):

Links are to the Brickipedia pages for the heroes/villains:

Unknown 1 Is indeed [Falcon](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Falcon) 

Unknown 2 is [Cyborg](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Cyborg) 
Unknown 3 is indeed [Antman](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Ant-Man) 
Unknown 4 is [Braniac](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Brainiac) 
Unknown 5 is [Hawkman](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Hawkman)

Comment: And the one labeled Deadpool is definitely [Carnage](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Carnage).

Comment: He is indeed, I didn't actually see his note of the *s meaning unknowns. @jamesdlin

Answer (score 10):

Bottom row "Unknown 5" is Hawkman.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkman
Not sure about the rest.